# Python shared BigQuery Client using Asyncio

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-asyncio

Using the package `google-cloud-bigquery` , I'm trying to make multiple queries spread across multiple coroutines to speed up a data validation process using `asyncio`.

I'm using the `google-cloud-bigquery` library like so (pretty basic):

```py
client = bigquery.Client()
job = client.query(query)
results = job.result()
```

I'm use an `asyncio.Queue` to place the key bits of data for each query which will be processed in one of `x` number of "worker" classes.  I've created a class to queue the necessary work like so:

```py
async def queue_jobs(records):
    num_workes = min(10, len(records))

    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    for record in records():
        queue.put_nowait(record)

    results = {}
    tasks = []

    for i in range(num_workers):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(
            worker(
                f"worker-{i}",
                project_id=project_id,
                dataset_id=dataset_id,
                table=table,
                queue=queue,
                output=results
            )
        ))

    await queue.join()
    print("\nAll bigquery workers finished")
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()

    # Wait for all tasks to stop
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return results
```

The worker class uses `asyncio.to_thread` to wrap the actual db query in an async coroutine in order not to block.

```py
async def worker(
    name: str,
    project_id: str,
    dataset_id: str,
    table: str,
    queue: asyncio.Queue,
    output: dict,
):
    print("Instantiating BigQuery client")
    client = bigquery.Client()

    while not queue.empty():
        record = await queue.get()

        for result in await asyncio.to_thread(
            get_duplicate_rows,
            client=client,
            project_id=project_id,
            dataset_id=dataset_id,
            table=table,
            data=record,
        ):
            print(f"{name} results ({time.ctime()})")
            for result in results:
                # ... do stuff
            output.append(

        queue.task_done()
```

Functionally, the program works, but it appears the workers are operating sequentially based on my log output (adjusted to use 5 workers here) and based on the fact that it takes the same amount of time when I test ran this with synchronous code:

```
worker-0 results (Fri Jan 12 14:21:50 2024)
worker-1 results (Fri Jan 12 14:21:51 2024)
worker-2 results (Fri Jan 12 14:21:52 2024)
worker-3 results (Fri Jan 12 14:21:54 2024)
worker-4 results (Fri Jan 12 14:21:55 2024)
worker-0 results (Fri Jan 12 14:21:56 2024)
worker-1 results (Fri Jan 12 14:21:57 2024)
worker-2 results (Fri Jan 12 14:21:58 2024)
worker-3 results (Fri Jan 12 14:21:59 2024)
worker-4 results (Fri Jan 12 14:22:01 2024)
worker-0 results (Fri Jan 12 14:22:02 2024)
worker-1 results (Fri Jan 12 14:22:03 2024)
worker-2 results (Fri Jan 12 14:22:04 2024)
```

#### This works with Spanner

I've used this exact same paradigm with another portion of the code that uses the `google-cloud-spanner` library to asynchronously query large batches (~2000 ea) of records in Cloud Spanner.  The main difference is the client.  For Spanner, my method to queue workers creates a database instance and shares that across 20 workers:

```py
    instance_name = "instance_name"
    database_name = "db_name"
    client = spanner_v1.Client(project=project_id)
    instance = client.instance(instance_name)
    database = instance.database(database_name)

    for i in range(num_spanner_workers):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(
            spanner_worker(database, project_id, table, spanner_records, queue, lock)
        ))
```

The Spanner worker class uses `asyncio.to_thread` to wrap the db call just like the BigQuery worker does.  The speedup for reading 200K spanner records in 2K batch sizes was about 15-20x.

For the Spanner query, I use a `database.snapshot()` context manager:

```py
    with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
        results = snapshot.execute_sql(query)
        return list(results)
```

I was initially thinking it had something to do with using the `database.snapshot()` that allowed this to work so well, but I'm still ***not sure why the BigQuery reads aren't happening concurrently***.  Especially since each worker has its own client.  I'm not that well versed in the `google.` libraries so I'm sure I may have missed something, but any help would be greatly appreciated.